# How to render responsive website "Desktop-version" to fit on mobilescreen

Tags: responsive-design

I try to render "website-weight=1400px" on "Device-weight=375px" but it won't fit on device screen

```
function rescreen(x) {
    var screen = x
    localStorage.setItem("screen", x);
    // var maxc = localStorage.getItem("")
    var screen = localStorage.getItem("screen")
    if (screen == 1) {
        screenx = "width=1400,initial-scale=1"
        $('body').addClass('dev');
    } else {
        screenx = "width=device-width,initial-scale=1"
    }
    document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').setAttribute("content", screenx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drunged way ,After I try for an hour I just change "initial-scale=1" to "initial-scale=-3" then it work for me.

[Metatags information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)